# Fixed formula when inserting rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs, excel-indirect

I am using the following formula in an Excel sheet, that performs the SUM in a range of cells from another sheet (ITEMS CONTROL):

```
=SUMIF('ITEMS CONTROL'!$B$2:$B$20000,B$1,'ITEMS CONTROL'!$C$2:$C$20000)
```

My issue is that when inserting rows in the sheet ITEMS CONTROL, the formula changes as follows:

After inserting 18 rows:

```
=SUMIF('ITEMS CONTROL'!$B$20:$B$20018,B$1,'ITEMS CONTROL'!$C$20:$C$20018)
```

After inserting another 18 rows:

```
=SUMIF('ITEMS CONTROL'!$B$38:$B$20036,B$1,'ITEMS CONTROL'!$C$38:$C$20036)
```

What should I change to keep always the original formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'ITEMS CONTROL'!$B$2:$B$20000"),B$1,INDIRECT("'ITEMS CONTROL'!$C$2:$C$20000"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use whole columns like this:

`=SUMIF('ITEMS CONTROL'!$B:$B$,B$1,'ITEMS CONTROL'!$C:$C)`

There are no efficiency implications - `SUMIF` only calculates the `"used range"`, even if you specify a bigger range